# Replacing cid src with base64

Tags: python, html

Say I have HTML (actually an e-mail) containing multiple `<img>`'s with a cid: reference. I would like some python code to replace them one by one with their respective base64 version of the original image. I know how to get the image and base64-encode them but how can I replace subsets of a string with specific other strings (the encoded variants of the images)...

replace(A,B) just replaces everything to the same thing... can any one help me with the thinking process :)

Sample input:

```
><a href="https://urlshortener.teams.microsoft.com/8D8660148021F90-7-11" style="text-decoration:none">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></td><td valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle; font-size:0"><a href="https://urlshortener.teams.microsoft.com/8D8660148021F90-7-10" style="text-decoration:none"><img height="16" width="14" style="vertical-align:middle; height:16px; width:14px" data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" src="cid:9A5CA00DCF7842D99534F2F486FB7E5A"></a></td><td valign="middle" width="5" style="width:5px"><a href="https://urlshortener.teams.microsoft.com/8D8660148021F90-7-9" style="text-decoration:none">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></td><td valign="middle"><a href="https://urlshortener.teams.microsoft.com/8D8660148021F90-7-8" style="vertical-al
```

Output would be the whole thing with src= replaced by

```
src="data:image/png;base64, <!-- base64encoded picture -->"
```

And that for every respective image in the source string (html).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at the code, `document.replace('cid:9A5CA00DCF7842D99534F2F486FB7E5A', 'data:image/png;base64, <!-- base64encoded picture -->')` isn't working?

Comment: Yes, but that would replace only one specific occurence.. I want them all replaced by their respective base64 encoded versions

Comment: You can put the `.replace(...)` inside the loop, to replace all occurences of `cid:...` - find all `cid:...`, put them into a list, encode them to base64 and replace them all.

Answer (score 0):

For if anyone may need this. With help of @Andrej Kesely if constructed this solution:

```
@login_required
def get_mail(request):
    message = Message.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST['id']))
    html = message.html\
        .replace('<pre', '<code style="white-space: line-wrap;"')\
        .replace('</pre', '</code>')
    for pic in re.finditer(r'cid:([^"]+)', html):
        attm = MessageAttachment.objects.get(message=message, headers__contains=pic[1])
        b64 = base64.b64encode(open('/media/' + str(attm.document), 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8')
        html = re.sub(r'src=".+"', f'src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {b64}"', html)

    return render(request, "message.j2.html", {'message': message, 'html': html})
```